# DSE opscenter cleanup: error at startup "wrong number of argument"

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

When trying to launch a cleanup on one or several nodes (running DSE 4.8.8)  using opscenter 5.2.4, I get the following error:

```
2016-06-06 07:44:33+0000 [Live]  WARN: Marking request '172.31.62.218: /ops/cleanup' (739eb503-01c5-436f-950c-e4c00f21756e) as failed: javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
2016-06-06 07:44:33+0000 []  WARN: Marking request 95b6d679-261a-4871-b611-093066c53445 as failed: javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
2016-06-06 07:44:33+0000 [Live] ERROR: Rolling job failed: javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
2016-06-06 07:44:33+0000 [Live] ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/ClusterUtils.py", line 611, in run
        DefaultException: javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

2016-06-06 07:44:33+0000 [Live] ERROR: Action cleanup on hosts 172.31.62.218,172.31.56.97,172.31.47.213,172.31.47.212,172.31.57.165,172.31.34.155,172.31.44.166,172.31.50.186,172.31.45.28,172.31.53.208: Job failed: javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
2016-06-06 07:44:33+0000 [Live] ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 388, in errback
            self._startRunCallbacks(fail)
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 455, in _startRunCallbacks
            self._runCallbacks()
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 542, in _runCallbacks
            current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1076, in gotResult
            _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
            return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/ClusterUtils.py", line 617, in run

          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/ClusterUtils.py", line 611, in run

        twisted.python.failure.DefaultException: javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

I tried restarting the opscenter service to no avail.

I can run `nodetool ceanup` manually on nodes without any issue.

Datastax agent log on a failing node:

```
  INFO [qtp949713715-33] 2016-06-06 07:56:20,812 HTTP: :post /ops/cleanup {:req-id "534589d5-7f6f-4555-9b33-8a992e5d14ec", :keyspace "mainnet"} - 200
  INFO [Thread-55] 2016-06-06 07:56:20,817 Performing JMX operation on org.apache.cassandra.db:type=StorageService: :forceKeyspaceCleanup ("mainnet" #<String[] [Ljava.lang.String;@253a7c1f>)
  WARN [Thread-55] 2016-06-06 07:56:20,855 Exception while processing JMX data: javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
 ERROR [Thread-55] 2016-06-06 07:56:20,856 #<RuntimeMBeanException javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments>
 ERROR [Thread-55] 2016-06-06 07:56:20,870 javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
        DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:839 com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.rethrow
        DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:852 com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.rethrowMaybeMBeanException
        DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:821 com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke
                       JmxMBeanServer.java:801 com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke
                   RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487 javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation
                     RMIConnectionImpl.java:97 javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300
                   RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328 javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run
                   RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420 javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation
                    RMIConnectionImpl.java:848 javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke
                              (Unknown Source) sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke
          DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
                               Method.java:606 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
                     UnicastServerRef.java:322 sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch
                            Transport.java:202 sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run
                            Transport.java:199 sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run
                              (Unknown Source) java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged
                            Transport.java:198 sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall
                         TCPTransport.java:567 sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages
                         TCPTransport.java:828 sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0
                         TCPTransport.java:619 sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400
                         TCPTransport.java:684 sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run
                         TCPTransport.java:681 sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run
                              (Unknown Source) java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged
                         TCPTransport.java:681 sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run
                  ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
                   ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
                               Thread.java:745 java.lang.Thread.run
                     StreamRemoteCall.java:275 sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer
                     StreamRemoteCall.java:252 sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall
                           UnicastRef.java:161 sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke
                              (Unknown Source) com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.PRef.invoke
                              (Unknown Source) javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.invoke
                        RMIConnector.java:1022 javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.invoke
                              (Unknown Source) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
              NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
          DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
                               Method.java:606 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
                             Reflector.java:93 clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod
                             Reflector.java:28 clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod
                                   jmx.clj:304 clojure.java.jmx/invoke-signature
                               RestFn.java:146 clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo
                                  core.clj:623 clojure.core/apply
                                   jmx.clj:311 clojure.java.jmx/invoke
                               RestFn.java:142 clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo
                                  core.clj:621 clojure.core/apply
                             operations.clj:73 opsagent.jmx.operations/jmx-op-blocking![fn]
                                   jmx.clj:189 opsagent.jmx/create-jmx-pool[fn]
                               RestFn.java:410 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
                             operations.clj:73 opsagent.jmx.operations/jmx-op-blocking!
                               RestFn.java:151 clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo
                                  core.clj:625 clojure.core/apply
                               RestFn.java:533 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
                             operations.clj:85 opsagent.jmx.operations/jmx-op[fn]
                                   AFn.java:24 clojure.lang.AFn.run
                               Thread.java:745 java.lang.Thread.run
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
                              (Unknown Source) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
              NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
          DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
                               Method.java:606 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
                            MethodUtil.java:75 sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke
                              (Unknown Source) sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke
          DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
                               Method.java:606 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
                           MethodUtil.java:279 sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke
            StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112 com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2
             StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46 com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2
                    MBeanIntrospector.java:237 com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM
                         PerInterface.java:138 com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke
                         MBeanSupport.java:252 com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke
        DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819 com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke
                       JmxMBeanServer.java:801 com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke
                   RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487 javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation
                     RMIConnectionImpl.java:97 javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300
                   RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328 javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run
                   RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420 javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation
                    RMIConnectionImpl.java:848 javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke
                              (Unknown Source) sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke
          DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
                               Method.java:606 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
                     UnicastServerRef.java:322 sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch
                            Transport.java:202 sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run
                            Transport.java:199 sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run
                              (Unknown Source) java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged
                            Transport.java:198 sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall
                         TCPTransport.java:567 sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages
                         TCPTransport.java:828 sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0
                         TCPTransport.java:619 sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400
                         TCPTransport.java:684 sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run
                         TCPTransport.java:681 sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run
                              (Unknown Source) java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged
                         TCPTransport.java:681 sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run
                  ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
                   ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpsCenter 5.2.4 is not certified to work with DSE 4.8.8 at this time. That error message is a direct result of an interface changing in DSE 4.8.8 that OpsCenter 5.2.4 is not "prepared" for, so to speak. The upcoming OpsCenter 6.0 release will have DSE 4.8.8+ support. However, an internal ticket (OPSC-9089) has been created to capture this issue for OpsCenter versions 5.2.x.

Comment: Got it, thanks. However I have the exact same issue with DSE 4.8.7.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. This also is broken in OpsCenter for DSE 4.8.7.